# Python opencv filtering everything outside region of interest

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Given an image and a set of points (number of points >= 3), where the set of points would form a polygon which is my region of interest, my aim is to filter everything in this image that is outside this region of interest, while the area inside it is untouched.

For example, given an image of size `712 x 480 px` and the points

`[[120,160]
  [100,130]
  [120,100]
  [140,130]]`

What I have done is

```
#Create an array of object rect which represents the region of interest
rect = [[120,160], [100,130], [120,100],[140,130]]
mask = np.array([rect], dtype=np.int32)

#Create a new array filled with zeros, size equal to size of the image to be filtered
image2 = np.zeros((480, 712), np.int8)

cv2.fillPoly(image2, [mask],255)
```

After this step, `image2` would be an array that is 0 everywhere except in the area whose position is exactly the same as my region of interest. After this step what I did was:

```
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image2)
```

`image` here is my input image. I get this error:

```
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1021: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::binary_op
```

I do not really understand what I did wrong here. Also, is there any alternate solution to my problem? I am still very new to opencv and still learning everything as I go. If there is a better way to do/library to use please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found 1 solution to my problem. So instead of writing this

```
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image2)
```

I first turn `image2` into a binary mask, and then `bitwise_and` it with my original image. So the code should be like this

```
maskimage2 = cv2.inRange(image2, 1, 255)
out = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=maskimage2)
```

Doing this will make everything outside region of interest have binary value of 0. Please comment if you see any flaw.